# Is angular work equivalent to linear work?

Tags: classical-mechanics, rotational-dynamics, energy-conservation, work

When considering the definition of angular work, I assumed that it should reduce to the definition of linear work in order to tie in quite nicely with conservation of energy. However, further investigation has suggested otherwise. Consider the definition of angular work.

$W_{\alpha} = \int_{t_0}^t\tau\cdot\omega dt$

Which can be rewritten as

$W_{\alpha}  =  \int_{t_0}^t(r\times F) \cdot \bigg(\frac{r\times v}{{\Vert{r}\Vert}^2}\biggr) dt$

$  = \int_{t_0}^t\frac{1}{{\Vert{r}\Vert}^2}(r\cdot r)(F\cdot v)dt - \int_{t_0}^t\frac{1}{{\Vert{r}\Vert}^2}(r\cdot v)(F\cdot r)dt$

The integral on the left corresponds to linear work since $(r\cdot r)$ cancels with ${\Vert r\Vert}^{-2}$.

$W_{\alpha}  = W - \int_{t_0}^t\frac{1}{{\Vert{r}\Vert}^2}(r\cdot v)(F\cdot r)dt$

So apparently, $W_{\alpha} = W$ only if $r$ and $v$ are orthogonal for all $t$ or $r$ and $F$ are orthogonal for all $t$. Why should this be the case, and how does this affect rotational kinetic energy and energy conservation?

Comment: The question may not make sense.  Work is equivalent to energy.  Energy does not have a direction.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The expression you wrote down for the angular work implies that $\vec{r}$ is orthogonal to $\vec{v}$, because of the circular motion  at constant radius. If this is not the case, you need an additional term that accounts for the change in radius.
$$d\vec{R} = \frac{d\alpha}{dt} \hat{\varphi}dt + \frac{dr}{dt}\hat{r} dt$$

The notation is 2D here, $\vec{R}$ is the position in space, $\alpha$ is the angle in polar coordinates, $r$ is the radius, $\hat{\varphi}$ is the unit vector in the angular direction, and $\hat{r}$ is the radial unit vector.

Comment: I'm afraid I don't understand the reason for splitting up $\vec r$ into the radial and angular components as defined in $\frac{d\vec R}{dt}$. There were no restrictions placed on the definition of $\vec r$ so shouldn't its magnitude be allowed to vary in any arbitrary way?

Comment: But you did not account for the change of $r$ in your formula for the angular work. You need the total derivative which consists of an angular and a radial part. What you did is like saying in 2 dimensions that $W=\int F dx$ and then asking why the velocity must be normal to the $y$-direction in order for the formula to give the correct result.

Comment: I gather my definition of $W_{\alpha}$ only applies to special cases of planar circular motion then. If that is indeed the case, how should $W_{\alpha}$ be defined for motion in $n$ dimensions?

Comment: Do you mean in the general case or again in the special case of circular motion?

Comment: In the general case where position $\vec r$ is allowed to vary in any arbitrary way.

Comment: The most general case is always $dW=\vec{F} d\vec{x}$ where $\vec{F}$ and $\vec{x}$ are n-dimensional cartesian vectors. Then you can always make a coordinate transformation to polar or spherical coordinates to split the work into a radial and an angular part. For the general case, talking if *only* angular work does not make sense, or at the very least, does not account for all the work being performed.